# using wp_tag_cloud with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm building a site for an architect and each Project page has a custom taxonomy called Project Services where the client can add various tags. I want to display them in a tag cloud so I'm using this:

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'project_services', 'separator' => ', ') ); ?>
```

But - the problem is that on each Project page, it's displaying *all* the various Project Services tags in the database, instead of on a per page basis. Any ideas?

Comment: you are welcome and glad it works. However, please don't use answers to leave comments, when you'll get 50+ rep you can comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the normal behavior of `wp_tag_cloud`: it show all tags, not only the tags for a specific post, even if inserted in a singular page. However, that function has an option **include** that let you define the tags to include (must be comma separed list of tag ids).

So, in your template file, pass that param to `wp_tag_cloud` using as value the list of tag ids of current post, that you can retrieve using [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) and [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'project_services' );
$tag_list = implode(',', wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id') );
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'project_services',
  'separator' => ', ',
  'include' => $tag_list
);
wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

In this way only page related tags will be shown in tag cloud.